# Core Text - Small frame too much text - How do I add three dots?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text

I'm using *Core Text* to render some text in a small frame. *Core Text* is good at calculating how much of a string that fits in a frame, but if it's too long and needs too be cut, I want to indicate this by adding three dots. Is it possible? How? I've Googled it, without any luck.

Comment: Was my answer of any use to you?

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head couldn't you do something like this:

```
CFRange visibleRange = CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange(frame);
int index = (visibleRange.loc + visibleRange.length) - 3; // -3 to make sure the three dots are visible

NSMutableString *newString = [text mutableCopy];
[newString insertString:@"..." atIndex:index]

// Re-create framesetter and frame with new string. Redraw frame.
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CTParagraphStyle for the text and set kCTLineBreakByTruncatingTail as the line break mode.